# Can't search for places like "Blood bank"

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

i'm developing an android app where user can see its current location and nearby blood banks on google maps.So i'm using Google-places-API for this and i'm getting correct results while i search for places type supported by google-places-API(for more info see:**https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types**) but unfortunately google doesn't support places type ="Blood bank" so how do i go about it...

Answer (score 0):

There's a variety of optional parameters, one of which is "keyword". You can try searching for "Blood bank". This doesn't necessarily mean you'll get them all, though, since it's not a supported type. There's not a 100% way to get all the blood banks around without it being a type that's supported.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

You could also include "health", which is a supported type, and then check inside your results to see if the words "blood bank" are written anywhere.

Comment: "health" is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You can search using [replace the place name with required place name](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=blood%20banks%20in%20delhi&key=AIzaSyCfC**S9fGGAh**********)

you can use geocoding and get the Locality to find the nearby blood banks